# How to format chromedriver performance log to use them into the chrome dev tool timeline viewer?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

I am collecting performance logs from Chromedriver.

I'd like to know if there is a way to make the output compatible with the Chrome development tools timeline viewer.